# GWT-EXT tree xml Error

Tags: java, json, gwt-ext

i am new to GWT GWT-EXT and i mimic it's demo
the problem is where i should put **xml** file

```
final TreePanel treePanel = new TreePanel() {
        {
            setAnimate(true);
            setEnableDD(true);
            setContainerScroll(true);
            setRootVisible(true);
        }
    };

 final XMLTreeLoader loader = new XMLTreeLoader() {
        {
            setDataUrl("countries-cb.xml");
            setMethod("get");
            setRootTag("countries");
            setFolderIdMapping("@id");
            setLeafIdMapping("@id");
            setFolderTitleMapping("@title");
            setFolderTag("team");
            setLeafTitleMapping("@title");
            setLeafTag("country");
            setQtipMapping("@qtip");
            setDisabledMapping("@disabled");
            setCheckedMapping("@checked");
            setIconMapping("@icon");
            setAttributeMappings(new String[]{"@rank"});
        }
    };
    AsyncTreeNode root = new AsyncTreeNode("Countries", loader);

    treePanel.setRootNode(root);
    treePanel.render();

    root.expand();
    treePanel.expandAll();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i put it under **`projectName/war/projectName/xmlfile.xml`** and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/tree/TreeLoader.html#setDataUrl%28java.lang.String%29

setDataUrl takes a URL parameter for the XML data source.

Perhaps you're stuck on "how can I serve an XML file"?